# Capture field value in Remote class

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

My understanding of the Remote validation is that the model field name you apply it to has to be the same as the variable name in the class that does the validation in the controller and the value is passe din the background.

so,

```
[Remote("doesUserNameExist", "Treeview", AdditionalFields = "SomeStuff", HttpMethod = "POST", ErrorMessage = "Already exists")]
public string userName { get; set; }


public JsonResult doesUserNameExist(string userName)
    {
    }
```

Comment: That's correct (although you have specified additional fields so the signature would need to be `public JsonResult doesUserNameExist(string userName, string SomeStuff)`). What problems are you having?

Comment: Hi Stephen 

In the class I wanted to dynamically set the value so the variable doesn't have to be the same name as the field the Remote validation is being used for.

Comment: Can't be done.  Attributes are static metadata and can only accept constants

Comment: Ok thanks, so if for example you wanted to validate 10 fields first you would need to create this 10 times? there is no way of making it dynamic to apply to all assuming all 10 values you are validating had unique names

Comment: Hard to imagine you would have 10 fields in a that need remote validation? Can you give an example of what your trying to achieve.

Comment: I started looking to use this for a maintenance section of a web app for where power users could enter new looks ups, such as title, job title, internal classification etc 

the idea was to dynamically capture the value and field name so it could be passed to a store procedure and used to look up the correct column and match the value in stead of duplicating the code for each model field this was going to be used on.